# Debug physics view?

Tags: scenekit

I've worked with 2D game libraries which have a handy setting to display the world's physics. This is useful when debugging physics problems, e.g. if the physics position is out of sync or scaled wrongly compared to the regular rendering.

Is there such a flag in SceneKit?

I have a couple of objects which are clearly not touching but I'm getting physicsWorld:didBeginContact: callbacks. I'm wondering which object is modeled incorrectly and so I'd like to see the physics world visualized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In OS X 10.11 and later, iOS 9 and later, and tvOS, you can set the [`debugOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/debugOptions) property on your `SCNView` to include the `SCNDebugOptionShowPhysicsShapes` flag.

---

In iOS 8.x, there's no way to show physics shapes. You can either do your physics debugging on a device running a newer iOS version, or do it on a Mac version of your app. (The SceneKit APIs are near identical on Mac and iOS, you can pretty trivially build a Mac test harness for your SceneKit content even if you're only shipping your app on iOS.)

There's no `debugOptions` in OS X 10.10, but if you set the `showsStatistics` flag for your view you'll get a little status readout at the bottom that shows frame rate and other useful stuff. Click the eye button there to show another window with all sorts of debugging controls—one of which is a checkbox to show physics bodies.

Comment: To show the physics bodies in the scene on iOS you can set the debug option:
`sceneView.debugOptions = SCNDebugOptionShowPhysicsShapes;`

Comment: This answer predates iOS 9, where `debugOptions` was introduced. Time for an edit...

Comment: You might want to try this syntax for more recent versions:
`sceneView.debugOptions = [.showWireframe, .showBoundingBoxes, .showPhysicsFields]`

Answer (score 1):

```
scnView.debugOptions = SCNDebugOptions.showPhysicsShapes
```